# Multidimensional Arrays Memory Usage in C (Heap)

Tags: c, memory-management, multidimensional-array, heap-memory

I have a problem to understand the memory usage of the following Code:

```c
typedef struct list{
    uint64_t*** entrys;
    int dimension;
    uint64_t len;
} list;

void init_list(list * t, uint64_t dim, uint64_t length, int amount_reg)
{
    t->dimension = dim;
    t->len=length;
    t->entrys = (uint64_t ***) malloc(sizeof(uint64_t**)*length);
    uint64_t i;
   for(i=0;i<length;i++)
   {
       t->entrys[i] = (uint64_t **) malloc(sizeof(uint64_t *)*dim); 
       int j;
       for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
       {
           t->entrys[i][j]=(uint64_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint64_t)*amount_reg);
       }
   }
}

int main()
{
     list * table = (list *) malloc(sizeof(list));
     init_list(table,3,2048*2048,2);
     _getch();
}
```

What i want to do is allocating a 3d-Array of uint64_t elements like table[4194304][3][2].
The taskmanager shows a memory usage of 560MB. cO
If i try to calculate the memory usage on my own i can't comprehend that value.
Here is my calculation (for a x64 System):

```
2^20 * 8 Byte (first dimension pointers)
+ 2^20 * 3 * 8 Byte (second dimension pointers)
+ 2^20 * 3 * 2 * 8 Byte (for the values itsself)

= 2^20 * 8 Byte * 10 = 80MB
```

Maybe I'm totaly wrong with that calculation or my code generates a huge amount of overhead?!

If so, is there a way, to make this program more memory efficent?
I can't imagine that for something like `~2^23 uint64_t` values so much memory is needed (cause `2^23*8Byte` are just `64MB`)

Comment: There is no "multidimensional array" in your code.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! Note: Being a three star programmer is no compliment.

Comment: It could be the `malloc` overhead that bites you. Your code does 2²²×3 calls to `malloc()`, it would be better if you allocated one chunk of memory and splitted it up yourself.

Comment: @FUZxxl can u give an example, how to do that?

Comment: @Memphisd Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does 2²² · 4 + 1 = 16777217 calls to `malloc()`. For each allocated memory region, `malloc()` does a little bookkeeping. This adds up when you do that many calls to `malloc()`. You can reduce the overhead by calling `malloc()` fewer times like this:

```
void init_list(list * t, int dim, uint64_t length, int amount_reg)
{
    uint64_t ***entries = malloc(sizeof *entries * length);
    uint64_t **seconds = malloc(sizeof *seconds * length * dim);
    uint64_t *thirds = malloc(sizeof *thirds * length * dim * amount_reg);

    uint64_t i, j;

    t->entrys = entries;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        t->entrys[i] = seconds + dim * i;
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
            t->entrys[i][j] = thirds + amount_reg * j + amount_reg * dim * i;
    }
}
```

Here we call `malloc()` only three times, and memory usage goes down from  561272 KiB to 332020 KiB. Why is the memory usage still so high? Because you made a mistake in your computations. The allocations allocate this much memory:

- entries: `sizeof(uint64_t**) * length` = 8 · 2²²
- seconds: `sizeof(uint64_t*) * length * dim` = 8 · 2²² · 3
- thirds:  `sizeof(uint64_t) * length * dim * amount_reg` = 8 · 2²² · 3 · 2

All together we have (1 + 3 + 6) · 8 · 2²² = 335544320 bytes (327680 KiB or 320 MiB) of RAM which closely matches the amount of memory observed.

How can you reduce this amount further? Consider transposing your array so the axes are sorted in ascending order of size. This way you waste much less memory in pointers. You could also consider allocating space for the values only and doing index computations manually. This can speed up the code a lot (less memory accesses) and saves memory but is tedious to program.

Comment: just stumbled about this post again, i think it has to be: thirds + amount_reg * j + amount_reg * dim * i;
in the most inner loop

Comment: @Memphisd Thank you for correcting this. What a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

4194304 is not 2^20, its more like 2^22, so your calculation is off by at least a factor of 4. And you also allocate a set of pointers to point to other data, which takes space. In your code, the first malloc allocates 
2048*2048 *pointers*, **not** a single pointer to that many items.

You should also use best practice for dynamic allocation:

1) Do not cast the malloc return

2) always use `expression = malloc(count * sizeof *expression);` This way you can never get the sizes wrong, no matter how many pointer levels you use in the expression. E.g.

```
 t->entrys       = malloc(length     * sizeof *t->entrys);
 t->entrys[i]    = malloc(dim        * sizeof *t->entrys[i]);
 t->entrys[i][j] = malloc(amount_reg * sizeof *t->entrys[i][j]);
```

Comment: ohh, ok you are right. But nevertheless, if i calculate with 2^22 it's 320MB. Which "pointers to point to other data" do u mean? And why they take 160MB of memory?

Comment: @Memphisd I mean the first malloc. It allocates storage for 4 million pointers, then you allocate 4 million more pointers to initialize them in the `i` loop. I think you've got it all backwards. You should allocate a few (2*3) large arrays of 4 million items. The loops should be turned inside-out.